# What is the difference between armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am working on an Android App on Kivy. I am using Buildozer to compile an APK file.
In the Buildozer spec file, there's a setting `android.arch = armeabi-v7a`, I didn't understand this.

Also, when I generated the APK file using the command `buildozer -v android debug` and installed it using the command `adb install bin/<appname>.apk` - it didn't Open on my Android Phone.

Answer (score 77):

To be clear, these are not instruction sets. They are ABIs, which compile into instruction sets. Most devices today are `arm64-v8a`, the really cheap devices are `armeabi-v7a` to save cost, and almost none are `x86` or `x86_64`.

e.g. The `armeabi-v7a` ABI compiles to `armeabi`, `thumb-2` and `VFPv3-D16` instruction set, but `arm64-v8a` ABI compiles to `AArch64` instruction set.

[image: Supported ABIs table 1 from https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis]

> Each combination of CPU and instruction set has its own Application
> Binary Interface (ABI). An ABI includes the following information:
>
> The CPU instruction set (and extensions) that can be used. The
> endianness of memory stores and loads at runtime. Android is always
> little-endian. Conventions for passing data between applications and
> the system, including alignment constraints, and how the system uses
> the stack and registers when it calls functions. The format of
> executable binaries, such as programs and shared libraries, and the
> types of content they support. Android always uses ELF. For more
> information, see ELF System V Application Binary Interface. How C++
> names are mangled. For more information, see Generic/Itanium C++ ABI.
> [source](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis)

Comment: A bit more context from Tensorflow Lite [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/android/development#lite_lib): `Unless you are targeting specific hardware, you should omit the x86, x86_64, and arm32 ABIs in most cases.` Since `armeabi` is the arm 32-bit, this means you can drop support for everything except `arm64-v8a`.