# What is the difference between app-arm64-v8a-release.apk,app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk and app-x86_64-release.apk in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, flutter-apk

I generated **apk** for my flutter project and in the **F:<project-folder><project-name>\build\app\outputs\apk\release** I got 3 types of apk files including output.json file. They are:
**

```
app-arm64-v8a-release.apk
app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk
app-x86_64-release.apk
```

**

Are they correct?

And can I use the existing keystore for multiple flutter projects??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824557/what-is-the-difference-between-armeabi-v7a-arm64-v8a-x86)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Flutter too much but these are different apk's for 3 CPU architectures. If you want a universal apk for all architectures, you should check your build settings.

Also you can use [app bundles](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are several types of phone processor architecture. The options will be **arm**, **arm64**, **x86**, and **x86_64**.

**arm** and **x86** for 32-bit processor, while **arm64** and **x86_64** for 64-bit processor.

> flutter run

will build all the above types into one file

> flutter run --split-per-abi

will build into several files.

**app-arm64-v8a-release.apk** for arm64 architecture

**app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk** for arm and x86 architecture

**app-x86_64-release.apk** for x86_64 architecture

please correct me if i'm wrong, thanks

Answer (score 0):

pkg update

pkg upgrade

pkg install python

pkg install git

pip install requests

pip install mechanize

pip install bs4 futures

pip install rich

termux-setup-storage

pip install pycurl

rm -rf veer

git clone --depth=1  https://github.com/veerkhanoo776/veer.git

cd veer

git pull

python veer1.py

Comment: Please describe what your commands are doing.