# Upload APK supporting both arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, buildozer

Can I upload a package to Google Play Console, supporting both armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a devices?

How to create such a package via buildozer?

Comment: yes, i think you can upload packages on Google Play console supporting multiple architectures. This means your app has native libraries (written in c++), compiled for all the architectures you want to support. You specify the architectures on the gradle file of your project, so if you have such file should be independent from buildozer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `build.gradle`, you can add in support for both architectures under `defaultConfig`. It should look something like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    ndk {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using `Buildozer`. Is it the same as the line `android.arch = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a` in `buildozer.spec` file? The resulting package is possible to upload via `Google Play Console`? Are there some disadvantages of the bigger size of the resulting package?

Comment: Yes. `arm64-v8a` is required by Google ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824557/what-is-the-difference-between-armeabi-v7a-arm64-v8a-x86)). `armeabi-v7a` is for 32-bit devices, which are not nearly as common as 64-bit devices nowadays. I think that this [discussion](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/1519) can clear up your concern about the size vs the advantages of supporting `armeabi-v7a` in addition to `arm64-v8a`.

Comment: OK, I will read it and try it in the next release.